# Can I mount a BTRFS snapshot of a live filesystem?

Tags: btrfs

I wonder if it is possible to mount one or more snapshots of the same BTRFS filesystem for analytical purposes.

Comment: [That is a normal use][1],  well, mounting multiple snapshots of the same fs, I think you cannot have them rw, but I wouldn't even bet on that. Give it a try


  [1]: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#What_is_a_snapshot.3F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. It's Copy-on-Write FS, there's nothing wrong with that, moreover, there're cases when snapshots are made to be written and discarded then.